# Error in finreportr GetIncome(): Permission denied

Tags: r, xbrl

I am attempting to get income data with the following code in with quantmod in finreportr.

```
GetIncome('FB', 2016)
```

Which returns these errors:

> Error in fileFromCache(file.inst) :
>        Error in download.file(file, cached.file, quiet = !verbose) :
>        cannot open destfile 'XBRLcache/fb-20151231.xml', reason 'No such file or 
>        directory'
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>        In dir.create(new.cache.dir) :
>         cannot create dir 'XBRLcache', reason 'Permission denied'

Comment: `GetIncome` and the package finreportr have nothing to do with quantmod. Check your sessionInfo and check if XBRL_0.99.18 is loaded via a namespace. I cannot reproduce your error. It works fine for me.

Comment: @phiver Yes, XBRL_99.18 is loaded via namespace.